# Highlight tableviewcell for a specific time

Tags: ios, uitableview, highlighting

How can i highlight a uitableviewcell only for a specific period of time without selecting it? I need to keep a cell highlighted for suppose 3 seconds and it then get dehighlighted. Basically i am developing a book type application where cells are in synch with audio. i have populated the tableviewcells with text and also I have timings for how long to keep a cell highlighted.

Comment: Do you know how to highlight a cell? Do you know how to unhighlight a cell? Do you know how to use an NSTimer? Post what you have tried and researched.

Comment: I would say , keep the cell selected for a certain span, then deselect it. If that becomes difficult, you can always reloadTableview, adding a boolean in the cellforRowAtIndexPath to determine if the cell should be highlighted or not...... But I would prefer the former over latter

Comment: @rmaddy yes i know how to highlight a cell and to use timers. But i don't know to select a single cell. Using [cell setHighlighted:YES animated:YES]; in a WillDisplay delegate method will cause all cells to highlight but how could i select individual cells keeping in mind i am using master-detail view controller. I also have created a custom cell where i declares my labels of cells for populating data. should i declare timers in customer cell class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API for setting a `UITableViewCell`'s highlight state is `setHighlighted:animated:` so assuming you just need a simple highlight the work is half done.

Using the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, notify the cell that it has become visible through some method you define in the subclass. That method will cause the cell to highlight itself and start a timer for as long as you want the cell to remain highlighted. When the timer fires, cause the cell to remove the highlight.

You will of course have to guard against timers remaining active if a cell scrolls out of view, so invalidate timers and reset the highlight state during `prepareForReuse:`

Comment: if i declare [cell setHighlighted:YES animated:YES]; in willDisplayCell delegate method, it will for sure highlight all cells. but as you have mentioned that i can declare some method in subclass and call this method using timers, i am not sure how can pass individual cell parameter to select individual cells for that purpose? (i am sorry if i've asked stupid question i am quite new to programming)

Comment: OK. If you don't want to highlight every cell as it appears, you can cause this to happen to individual cells. Just use cellForRowAtIndexPath: to get the individual cell when you decide you need a cell corresponding to some indexPath highlighted, then send the message to that cell to cause the highlight/de-highlight. cellForRowAtIndexPath: is OK for you to use (in addition to being a method for the table view to use).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make custom UITableViewCell class. When cell will be initialized, use a NSTimer with a specific time interval. Make a custom method and pass it in below NSTimer method as selector (in custom cell class)--

[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats]

In selector method you can set the tableViewCell background colour to show it highlighted.